# $*$-homomorphism of $C^*$-algebras and representations

Tags: representation-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, continuous-homomorphisms

For $i=1,2$, let $\mathcal{A}_i$ be an abstract $C^*$-algebra and $\pi_i : \mathcal{A}_i \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_i)$ a $C^*$-representation. Let $\alpha: \mathcal{A}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{A}_2$ a *-homomorphism.

I'm looking for a theorem that may assert that there exists a unique $*$-homomorphism $\tilde{\alpha} : \pi_1 (\mathcal{A}_1)'' \rightarrow \pi_2 (\mathcal{A}_2)''$ of von Neumann algebras such $ \tilde{\alpha}(\pi_1(a))= \pi_2(\alpha(a))$ for all $a \in \mathcal{A}_1$. ¿In which topology $\tilde{\alpha}$ is continuous?

Please, I need references about such a theorem.

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such extension does not usually exist. For instance take $\mathcal A_1=\mathcal A_2=UHF(2^\infty)$. Let $\pi_1:\mathcal A_1\to \mathcal B(\mathcal H_1)$ be a Powers representation such that $\pi_1(\mathcal A_1)''$ is a type III factor $M$. And let $\pi_2:\mathcal A_2\to \mathcal B(\mathcal H_2)$ be GNS from the trace, so $\pi_2(\mathcal A_2)''$ is the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor $R$.

Take $\alpha(x)=x$, the identity isomorphism.

Now you want a $*$-homomorphism $\bar\alpha: M\to R$. We may assume $\bar\alpha(1)=1$ (otherwise, replace $R$ with $\bar\alpha(1) R\bar\alpha(1)$, which is still a hyperfinite II$_1$). Given any projection $p\in M$, we have $p\simeq 1$, so $\bar\alpha(p)\simeq 1$; as this last equivalence happens in a II$_1$-factor, we have $\bar\alpha(p)=1$ for all projections $p\in M$. But then $1=\bar\alpha(1)=\bar\alpha(p+1-p)=\bar\alpha(p)+\bar\alpha(1-p)=2$. So $\bar\alpha$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'm not sure if I completely understood your counterexample. But, do the representations of your example are faithful? If not, do you think that the statement could be true for faithful representations? Furthermore, at least could be the statement true when $\mathcal{A_1}=\mathcal{A_2}$, faithful $pi_1=\pi_2$ and $\alpha$ a $*$-automorphism? Thanks for any insight into these new questions.

Comment: The representations I mention are faithful. For you second question, I need to think about it.